# Node tree traversal with right and left child access

Tags: java, tree, traversal

Trying to traverse a tree and getting null value for my array.  I need to traverse the tree that only allows access to the right and left children with no root in the class definition for the Node class.

```
class Tree<T> {
 Tree(T x) {
   value = x;
 }
 T value;
 Tree<T> left;
 Tree<T> right;
}

public int[] traverseTree(Tree<Integer> t) {
   Stack<Tree<Integer>> stack = new Stack<Tree<Integer>>();
    Tree<Integer> node = root;

    while (node != null) { 
        stack.push(node);
        node = node.left;
    }

    int[] result = new int[stack.size()];
    int i = 0;
    while (stack.size() > 0) {
        node = stack.pop();
        if(node != null) {
            result[i] = node.value;
            i++;
        }
        if (node.right != null) {
            node = node.right;

            while (node != null) {
                stack.push(node);
                node = node.left;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

It takes an input of

```
t = {
"value": 1,
"left": {
    "value": 2,
    "left": null,
    "right": {
        "value": 3,
        "left": null,
        "right": null
    }
},
"right": {
    "value": 4,
    "left": {
        "value": 5,
        "left": null,
        "right": null
    },
    "right": null
   }
 }
```

This should return [1,2,4,3,5] and I am getting []. I've also tried looping like

```
 if(root != null) {
     queue.add(root);
  }

 while(root.left != null) {
   while(root.right != null) {
      queue.add(root);
      root = root.right;
   }
   queue.add(root);
   root = root.left;
}
```

This also doesn't work. This too will give me back a [] array.  The traversal should print the tree from left to right on the tree level indicated by the tree height (which is the level). Any thoughts?

Comment: @azurefrog editted the question to include what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> It...should return t = [1,2,4,3,5] and I am getting [].

Well, let's look at the for-loop you're using to populate your `Queue`:

```
for (Tree<Integer> node = root; node != null; node = queue.poll()) {
    //stuff
}
```

What you're doing here is looping until `queue.poll()` returns `null`, and if we look at the [javadoc for `ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html#poll--), we see that `poll()`

> Retrieves and **removes the head** of the queue represented by this deque (in other words, the first element of this deque), or **returns null if this deque is empty**.

So, basically you are looping until your `Queue` is empty, then creating an array based on its size to return.  Since its size is always zero, you always return a zero-length array.

It looks like you're looking to do a Preorder traversal, so what you need to do is to rewrite your method using a [proper algorithm](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing_2009/AQA/Problem_Solving,_Programming,_Operating_Systems,_Databases_and_Networking/Programming_Concepts/Tree_traversal_algorithms_for_a_binary_tree#Preorder).

If you're committed to a non-recursive traversal, [here's an algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion/) for doing it that way, instead.

Comment: Thanks that was were I started but was running into to issues. @azurefrog

Comment: I am trying to do this non-recursively and I followed the algorithm, as edited above, which still doesn't work. Any thoughts?